# In Kentico 7 I need to get attachment information from the attachment URL

Tags: kentico

When Kentico documents have images embedded in them, the image is inserted into the HTML as an `<img>` tag. I need to determine if this image is hosted by Kentico and if so, use the Kentico API to retrieve the database information for it.

So far I have parsed the File GUID out of the URL like this:

```
    const string attachmentPrefix = "~/getattachment/";
    if (imageElement.LinkAddress.StartsWith(attachmentPrefix))
    {
        var start = attachmentPrefix.Length;
        var end = imageElement.LinkAddress.IndexOf("/", start);
        var fileGuidString = imageElement.LinkAddress.Substring(start, end - start);
        var fileGuid = new Guid(fileGuidString);
        var info = AttachmentHistoryInfoProvider.GetInfoByGuid("-- what goes here --", fileGuid);
    }
```

But I have not found any useful methods in the Kentico API that will retrieve information about the attachment from the GUID. The closest I found was `AttachmentHistoryInfoProvider.GetInfoByGuid()` but it takes an `objectType` parameter that I can't find any documentation for.

Does anyone know how to get information on attachments in Kentico 7 starting from a File GUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you're talking about images in the media library, but are trying to use the `AttachmentHistoryInfoProvider` in your code sample.  I think it depends on what you are referring to when you say '*documents have media library images embedded in them*'; in what way are you embedding them? Perhaps using the *Editable image* web part for example.

- If you are using files from the media library, you should try using `MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo(Guid, string)` which takes the Guid of the file and the site code name.  This will return you a `MediaFileInfo` class.  You can find it in the `CMS.DataEngine` assembly in Kentico 7.  For a file from a media library, I'd expect to see a URL like `/SampleSite/media/cats/nohandskitten.aspx` to be rendered.
- If you're not using images from the media library, but are inserting directly into content, then yes - this is an attachment.  Rather than using `AttachmentHistoryInfoProvider`, you should use `AttachmentInfoProvider`.  Calling `AttachmentInfoProvider.GetAttachmentInfo(Guid, string)` with the Guid of the file and the site code name will return the `AttachmentInfoObject`.  I believe the `AttachmentHistoryInfoProvider` will only return things to you if you have object versioning enabled.  For a file from an attachment, I'd expect to see a URL like `/getattachment/75408145-0995-45dc-943a-d27296a45327/nohandskitten.jpg.aspx`.

These InfoProviders do fundamentally different things, so long as you know what type of information you're looking for, you should be able to choose the correct one

If you don't have it already, the API reference for Kentico 7 may be helpful: https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/kenticocms_api.zip

Comment: I was trying the `AttachmentHistoryInfoProvider` class because the url has the form `~/getattachment/{guid}/{filename}`.
I tried calling `MediaFileInfoProvider.GetInfoByGuid()` as you suggest, but it takes the same two parameters as `AttachmentHistoryInfoProvider.GetInfoByGuid()` and I still don't know what to pass for the `objectType` parameter.

Comment: I found `CMS.MediaLibrary.MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo()` in the help file that you posted, and it takes a Guid and a site name as parameters.
If you update your answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution in the help file - I've updated the answer inline with that.  It's been a while since I did a v7 site, but I want to know what `objectType` should be now, so I think I might just go and restore an old project and find out.  If I figure it out, I'll post it in here. :)

Comment: So the `CMS.MediaLibrary.MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo()` method returns null for the guid from urls like this one. I tried a few others and discovered that  `CMS.DocumentEngine.AttachmentInfoProvider.GetAttachmentInfo` does return data, and so this appears to be the correct answer.
Maybe you could expand your answer to explain why these differences exist, and how to determine which function to call for a given Guid. Thanks.

Comment: I've added some more in there to cover the two different options (media vs. attachment). I think the key point is whether these are media library files or not.  I'd made the assumption that they are given your mention of them, but the URLs you're referring to are those of attachments.  Does that make sense?

Comment: In my case I am starting from a document in the Kentico document tree that contains `<img>` tags. My code has no way to determine how the user inserted the image into the document. The only information available in this case is the URL of the image. I want to determine the title, author and any other information available about the image.